# Recieivng a 'NoneType' 'append' in python 3

Tags: append, nonetype

I have this code and it keeps giving me the 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'. Can someone tells me what is wrong, please?

```
def extract():
    extracted_data = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Name','Last'])
    for jsonfile in glob.glob('file_1.json'):
        extracted_data = extracted_data.append(extract_from_json(jsonfile), ignore_index = True)
```

return extract

Comment: You're missing a closing `)` for your append. Typo? Your error is caused by `extracted_data`  being a `NoneType` and not a list (as you seem to expect it to be)

Comment: `append` doesn't return anything. It's an in-place operation.

Comment: How do I modify then?

Comment: Just get rid of `extracted_data =`. There's nothing to assign back to `extracted_data`.

Comment: I got rid of it, but now when i call the function it does not return the names and last names only <function extract at 0x00000200C6AF9820>

Comment: @MarkieRomano That's an unrelated problem. Look at your `return` statement and think about what variable you're returning.